# Generating migration from existing database in Yii or Laravel

Tags: php, database, yii, migration, laravel

I'm working on a project that has a fairly complex database (150+ tables). In order to be able to maintain changes, I've decided to add migrations, preferably using Yii or Laravel.

Does anybody know, if it is possible to generate a initial migration from an existing database?

Creating it by hand would:

- take for ever and
- be very error-prone.

If there is no way, does anybody know a good PHP-based framework, that supports such functionality?

Comment: There isn't an automated way of turning a existing db into laravel tables.

Answer (score 25):

Instructions for accomplishing this in Yii:

1. Add your database connection settings to `protected/config/console.php`.
2. Run `yiic migrate create initial` to create the stub code for the migration.
3. Copy contents of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmarston/5541632) to `protected/commands/InitialDbMigrationCommand.php`.
4. Run `yiic initialdbmigration 'name_of_your_database' > initial_migration.php` to generate `up()` and `down()` methods for initial database migration.
5. Copy and paste `up()` and `down()` methods from `initial_migration.php` to the file created in the `protected/migrations` folder in step 2.

Comment: Your answer led us [into an interesting discussion on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275485/1469208). Conlusions are, that your answer would be perfect, if you could include entire code from your gist below this answer (edit it and add this code, plese). I did it myself, but had to remove my change, because I was warned that I'm breaking license and only you (gist author) can add this code to your own answer. Will you, please, consider adding it?

Answer (score 4):

'[Doctrine Project](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)' (aka Doctrine) has the ability to create DB migrations for existing DB structures, so you can recreate the existing structure. It can be easily implemented in Symfony, Laravel, also in Yii and many frameworks.

Sample from:
http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/07-Migrations

> **From Database**
>
> If you have an existing database you can build a set of migration
>   classes that will re-create your database by running the following
>   command.
>
> ```
> $ ./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-db
> ```
>
> **From Models**
>
> If you have an existing set of models you can build a set of migration
>   classes that will create your database by running the following
>   command.
>
> ```
> $ ./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-models
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Laravel package I created that does exactly that. It automatically generates clean and accurate Laravel migrations from your existing database.

As it doesn't make any assumptions of the database, it should work on any database structure while even keeping the original index and foreign key names.

https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Answer (score 1):

Well since migration is about setting up your database structure and make changes to it, not to reflect a current database there is no such way.

And this is also not a step you have to make. You can start from where you are at the moment, which will make you able to rollback up to this point. Which means you can make migrations for your current tables without having to specify their entire structure, but just the changes only.

Let's say you have a table called user and want to add their firstname to it.

```
php artisan migrate:make add_firstname_to_user
```

Now go into `application/migrations` and find the migration file, add this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('user', function($table)
    {
        $table->string('firstname');
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::table('user', function($table)
    {
        $table->drop_column('firstname');
    });
}
```

Now you can add migrate it

```
php artisan migrate:install // if you haven't run this, should only be once
php artisan migrate
```

.. and rollback using

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

This will add or drop the column firstname, without affecting your table in any other way.

Comment: anyway, it would be nice to have such a facility, for generating the initial migration script for a new project which you already have a complete db structure for. EG: You may be migrating from another platform, or the db may have been changed since the last migration script, or you may have not used migration scripts before and wish to begin using them for an existing project. There are always special cases, and they are not always that special...

Comment: It would be quite nice...Other frameworks do this (like CakePHP) and the reason why is because it's FAR easier to build your schema in something like MySQL Workbench, etc. Though it's FAR easier to build your schema in PHP if you plan on changing databases (so it's agnostic). There is this package: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators  ... Which makes things a lot nicer (adds some CakePHP like functionality to Laravel).

Comment: And what is so wrong with exporting the schema in a tool like mysql workbench and loading this script initially, when setting up a new environment (maybe even within the first migration)? And after that starting to use migrations.

Answer (score 1):

As for Yii 1.x, *schmunk* has created a wonderful [`database-command`](https://github.com/schmunk42/database-command) yiic command.

**This command covers only up migrations. You must write your own down migrations**.

To use it:

1. Get [the newest version from GitHub](https://github.com/schmunk42/database-command/tags) and put it's contents into `/protected/commands` folder (create one, if it does not exist). Note, that you need to put contents *as is* ([**without subfolder**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#c18820) for this particular command), which is contrary to what we do for example for extensions.
2. Rename `EDatabaseCommand.php` file (and class inside) to `DatabaseCommand.php`, if you want to use `yiic database` command (as suggested in docs). Without this fix, you'll have to use `yiic edatabase` command, as [there's slight inconsistency between docs and the code](https://github.com/schmunk42/database-command/issues/17) (at least in the newest version, as of writing this; maybe *schmunk* is going to fix this).
3. Having this, navigate back to `protected` folder in your console and execute `yiic database dump migration_name --prefix=table_name`.

This will create a migration `protected/runtime/migration_name.php` file with proper date and time in the beginning of file name, filled with series of [`CDbMigration`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration/) commands to recreate your database schema. Visit "[Usage](https://github.com/schmunk42/database-command#usage)" section in the docs to read more about customizing command.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is: https://github.com/jamband/yii2-schemadump for Yii2
"This command to generate the schema from an existing database."

Comment: As it understand it, on SO, link-only answers are frowned upon due to linkrot.

Answer (score 0):

I use both Yii and Laravel and I could not find what you require for either of them. They both create empty files and you need to create the migration script yourself.
For a table of 150 tables it will be challenge to create the migrations yourself, but it is not quite as hard as you imagine. Because you already have the information on the fields it should not take so long to create.

Comment: i wrote script mysqlf in yii that generates a migration from an existing database.

Comment: Please share it :), I would love to take a look at it. Expecially in Yii.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, here's what you're going to need for Laravel: https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator

(version 4 at least, who knows how long this will work, Laravel changes too fast and has too many breaking changes)

You'll want to run `php artisan larry:fromdb` and it'll show you the tables...You can also exclude or only process certain tables (look at the readme).

Again, super super useful if you like to build your schema in something like MySQL Workbench. I also saw mention of a package that would parse the workbench files...But the link was dead.

You may also wish to use this larry package with: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators

You can then create scaffolding a la CakePHP style.

Alternatively, try this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator

Answer (score 0):

There is one now for Yii:

This allows a distributed team to easily update the db locally and then distribute it's updates with thee other developers automatically with the rest of the code via a versioning control system (I used git). It also performs a full initial db dump to xml and to a migration file.

project home:
https://code.google.com/p/yii-automatically-generated-migration-files/

source code:
https://code.google.com/p/yii-automatically-generated-migration-files/source/checkout

I've created it from scratch as I was annoyed with the fact that I had to do this manually in order to distribute it to my team.

Hope it helps!

Feel free to share bugs, improvements and comments.