# Create migration from existing database in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration

Is it possible to create a migration in Laravel 4 from an existing database?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605767/generating-migration-from-existing-databse-in-yii-or-laravel?rq=1

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator

Comment: Thanks mark.
tested it out and migration file seems to be accurate including relationships.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator) is the linked script, that does, what is asked here.

I also found [this tool](https://gist.github.com/bruceoutdoors/9166186) (actually a Gist code) and I highly prefer it for its simplicity.

Comment: also check out my extensive answer linked below, you might find it useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271670/reverse-engineering-or-auto-generations-of-entities-in-laravel/20274636#20274636

Comment: Gist code worked beautifully. Many thanks for the link!